# ssh как скопировать директорию с одного компа на другой?

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

У меня прокинут порт на другой комп по локалке. Как я могу скопировать файл из него на другой?

Comment: Наверное что-то в духе `tar czf - your-dir | ssh user@host tar xvf -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примеры, с использованием [SCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP):

```
scp -r path/to/local/dir user@example.com:/path/to/remote/dir
scp -r user@example.com:/path/to/remote/dir path/to/local/dir
```

Если прокинутый порт `ssh` нестандартный(не 22), то добавить параметр:

```
scp -P PORT_NUMBER -r ...
```